# java.lang.indexoutofboundsexception index 0 size 0

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I've been getting this java.lang.indexoutofboundsexception error when adding system functions objects in an array through checkbox:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet spis threw exception
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
at com.spis.dao.impl.CodesValueDaoImpl.getDescription(CodesValueDaoImpl.java:95)
at com.spis.bo.impl.CodesValueBoImpl.getDescription(CodesValueBoImpl.java:103)
at com.spis.controller.SystemUserController.viewPaged(SystemUserController.java:408)
at com.spis.controller.SystemUserController.systemUser(SystemUserController.java:48)
```

Here is the for the systemFunctions: whenever i add systemFunction to a user it displays the error or when the systemFunction colummn in the database is null. But when i set systemFunction=" " in the database the page displays correctly although withouth the array of systemFunctions obviously..

```
String[] systemFunctions=(String[])request.getParameterValues("systemFunctions");
String appendedSysFunctions ="";

//Append system functions
if(systemFunctions!=null){
    for(int i=0;i<systemFunctions.length;i++){
        if(i==(systemFunctions.length-1)){
        appendedSysFunctions+=systemFunctions[i];
        }
        else{
        appendedSysFunctions+=systemFunctions[i] + ",";
        }
    }
}
```

Another code:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(su.getAllowedSysFunc(), ",");
while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
    appendedSystemFunc = appendedSystemFunc + codesValueMethods.getDescription 
    (3, st.nextToken());
    if(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    appendedSystemFunc = appendedSystemFunc + ", \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `systemFunctions` has no elements. Debug your code.

Comment: It would really help if you'd format your code in a readable way - fix the indentation, and add some helpful whitespace within lines.

Comment: Also, it's not obvious that you've shown us `getDescription` at all - which line is throwing the exception? (The stack trace talks about descriptions - all the code you've shown us is about "system functions" and we've no idea what the relationship between those two is.)

Comment: @JonSkeet It's there, I think, in the second snippet. `codesValueMethods.getDescription(3, st.nextToken());` Though I do not think that helps us out at all. Rather, I'd think the problem is wherever `ArrayList#get` is.

Comment: @Radiodef: Well that's the call *to* `getDescription` (although we don't know what from). But we need the code for `getDescription` itself. There's still not enough to go on at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, I see what you mean. Yes.

Comment: @rez The point is that `CodesValueDaoImpl` calls `get` on an `ArrayList` in `getDescription` (line 95). That List is empty. That is where the exception is thrown. The code you've shown us doesn't tell us anything about the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You have to check `systemFunctions` whether it is null and whether its length is greater than 0:

```
if(systemFunctions!=null && systemFunctions.length>0){
  ...
}
```

Comment: No, because the `for` loop checks that immediately: `for(int i=0;i<systemFunctions.length;i++)`

Comment: Why would you want to let the execution even proceed to the `for` loop if the array is empty?

Comment: Because it's simpler to do that than to add a redundant check? Either way, this is certainly *not* the cause of the exception.

Comment: Already solved it, my mistake the array was fetching array of single letters instead of numbers. It should fetch "a" instead "1", and so on. Stupid mistake. Thanks for answering my questions anyways.. PEace..